# Two columns linked together when renaming in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am having an issue where two columns of my dataframe appear to be linked together. I need to specify the second column to be renamed "Project" by index (in the code below) because it has no column header, but for some files it appears to cause the next column with no header to be renamed "Project" as well. When I try to drop that column by index in the resulting dataset, both columns in the dataset are dropped.

> df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]: "Project"}

It appears to do this for some data files that I have but not others so it is unclear where the issue is or if it is due to my code below.

The dataset will look something like this:

> Classification | Category | Project .... | MTD Budget | Project

```
dfs=[]

for i in range(12):
    print (i)
    df = pd.read_excel(files[i],sheet_name = sheet,header = None, usecols=range(1,16))

for row in range(df.shape[0]): 

    for col in range(df.shape[1]):

        if df.iat[row,col] == 'Classification':
            row_start = row
            break
df = df.loc[row_start:]

new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header

df['Region'] = sheet
df['File'] = files[i].rsplit('/',1)[1]
df['Period'] = files[i].rsplit('Overview - ',1)[1][:-5]


df = df.dropna(axis='columns',how='all')
df = df.dropna(axis='index',how='all')

df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]: "Project"})
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]

df['Classification'] = df['Classification'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['Category'] = df['Category'].fillna(method='ffill')

dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: please give us a sample file to test out. thanks.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: IIUC: `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this hack would do:

```
col_to_change = 2
df.columns = (list(df.columns[:col_to_change]) +
              ['Project'] + 
              list(df.columns[col_to_change+1:]
             )
```

Or:

```
df.columns = [col if i!=col_to_change else 'Project' 
                  for i,col in enumerate(df.columns.to_list()) ]
```